# TFS2012 coexists with VS2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I'm interested in tfs 2012 but not all our projects and solutions are in vs2012 yet.
Can we install tfs 2012 but still use vs 2010 solutions/projects?
We do automated builds as well and keep our builds in the existing project versions?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can. The providers for TFS 2008, 2010 and 2012 will happily co-exist, and there are "forward compatibility" packs to allow (say) VS2010 to connect to TFS2012.

It is also worth noting that VS2012 is the first version of visual studio to have backwardly compatible solution files (so you can mix VS2012 and VS2010 to edit solutions - unless the solution depends on a feature specific to each, like Windows 8 Apps)

Comment: It is worth noting that some administration features in tfs2012 can only be done by using vs2012 and not vs2010 (example creating team projects).